# YII2 Gridview doesn't return selected rows (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectionColumn' of undefined yii.gridView.js:140)

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

i'm trayng to pass (with post) an array with selected keys from a gridview but i am getting always the same URL's error:

```
POST http://localhost/cngrx/web/index.php/ponenciaresumen/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems the code generete always this pattern: path/myController/[object%20Object] 
It's doesn't matter wich url i set, the code generete always the same url, and its not what i need. My code is this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#MyButton').click(function(){

       var keys = $('#w1').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
        $.post({
           url: 'myController/myAction', 
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {keylist: keys}

        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I've tried with absolutly url, and relatives one, but not. How can it be??

This is my action in myController:

```
 public function actionMyAction(    ) {
    if (isset($_POST['keylist'])) {
        $keys = \yii\helpers\Json::decode($_POST['keylist']);

        // you will have the array of pk ids to process in $keys
        // perform batch action on these keys and return status
        // back to ajax call above
    }
}
```

Thanks for advance!

Comment: What is ponenciaresumen? What is [object%20Object]?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn.html

Need `Class yii\grid\CheckboxColumn`

> var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens, as you put the grid into an pjax container?

if your not using Pjax, you should use element id #w1 instead of #grid.

Yii2 render this script

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#modal-upload').modal({"show":false});
    jQuery('#w0').yiiGridView({"filterUrl":"/advanced/backend/web/index.php?r=state%2Findex","filterSelector":"#w0-filters input, #w0-filters select"});
    jQuery('#w1').yiiGridView({"filterUrl":"/advanced/backend/web/index.php?r=state%2Findex","filterSelector":"#w1-filters input, #w1-filters select"});
    jQuery('#w1').yiiGridView('setSelectionColumn', {"name":"selection[]","multiple":true,"checkAll":"selection_all"});
    jQuery('#w2').yiiGridView({"filterUrl":"/advanced/backend/web/index.php?r=state%2Findex","filterSelector":"#w2-filters input, #w2-filters select"});
    });
```

I got no value or keys when i used Pjax on my GridView
But i got the keys when i used element id #w2 instead of #grid.

You can use this on your view

```
    $script = '
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      btnCheck  = $("#btn-check");
      btnCheck.click(function() {
        var keys = $("#w2").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");
        alert(keys);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "'.\yii\helpers\Url::to(['/controller/action']).'", 
            dataType: "json",
            data: {keylist: keys}
        });
      });
    });';
    $this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_END);
```

Comment: On `AppAsset.php`, add this property : `public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];` so the jQuery will be loaded at the beginning of the page. Then, change the selector to `$('.grid-view')` if you are using Pjax

Answer (score 0):

View the source of your code and check if checkbox has id "w1"  or "w0"  .. by default for me its 'w0' and I was able to fix my issue:

```
var keys = $('#w0').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#MyButton').click(function(){ 
    var keys = $('#w0').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    $.post("index.php?r=myController/myAction", {keylist: keys}, function(result){
        $("span").html(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.